# Hero Image Hides Content Until Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I love the Medium site, especially their [Beautiful Stories pages](https://medium.com/gender-justice-feminism/59fc5490b223). I'm trying to figure out how they handle these pages.

If your browser window is big enough, you're able to see the cover image and a bit of the content below.

[image]

If you resize your browser window, however, the bottom of the image touches the bottom of the browser window and resizes with the broswer window. Aldo the content is hidden until you scroll.

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how they're doing this and I've set up a CodePen wiht my basic page structure over here: http://codepen.io/realph/pen/luwdJ

Can anyone explain how I can achieve a similar effect?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**updated**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        var $winwidth = $(window).width();
        $("img.source-image").attr({
            width: $winwidth
        });
        $(window).bind("resize", function(){ 
            var $winwidth = $(window).width();
            var $winheight = $(window).height();
            $("img.source-image").css({
                'width': $winwidth,'height':$winheight
            });
         });
    });
```

The above script makes image width to change according to the screen width

And Css

```
img.source-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Or

```
#img.source-image {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

For more info follow this [Link](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/)

Comment: I've updated the CodePen above, but still can't get that to work with what you've posted.

Comment: @realph your bg-image is resizing now when I'm resize the browser... I have updated the script. If you want to change the height then use $(window).height();

Comment: I can't seem to get that to work either. It's not a case of my bg-image not resizing, but my `.cover` element stretching the fill the height of the window when the browser window's height shrinks to a certain height.

Comment: Try this plugin http://www.mobify.com/mobifyjs/v2/docs/capturing/      or use two different images for different resolutions with css media query. I don't know any other solutions... If this solves your problem then don't forget to accept this answer